# What's the auto scaling strategy of AWS ELB?

Tags: websocket, amazon-elb

We are trying to build a WebSocket server(with `500k` concurrent connections, but very low traffic) on AWS with ELB.

We tested single server with Public IP, it can handle more than `500k` connections.

But when we put the servers after the ELB, every server can only get `65536` connections.

And we can see a lot of `Spillover Count` on ELB Monitoring.

The document of ELB says they will auto scaling the ELB by changing the IP list in DNS.

But when I `dig` my domain, I always get the same IP list.

The ELB auto scaling seems not work.

Comment: as rumors says ELB automatically detect continuous load and scale themself if needed. So after some time in near future you achieve needed throughput:). But if you planing to achieve huge traffic burst you need to ask ELB pre-warming by aws support team through request as it says in https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1636185810492479#pre-warming Maybe it will help you

Comment: how many target nodes your using behind the load balancer ?

Comment: There is a probable explanation for this behavior, which is not properly related to "scaling" -- but first, to clarify, is this an ELB/1.0 ("classic") or ELB/2.0 ("application")?  How many availability zones are active on the balancer and the instances?

Comment: ...based on the mention of Spillover Count, I assume we're talking about a Classic ELB in TCP mode, so there are additional questions worth asking: how many instances are you testing with, are they spread across all zones, and do you have cross-zone balancing enabled?

Comment: @RuslanNeruka Thanks! I will contact AWS for pre-warming.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It's classic ELB, and the protocol is TCP. We have 2 EC2 backends.
And I have 4 test clients from another region.

Comment: Have you enabled cross-zone load balancing?  How long did you allow the test clients to continue to try to hit your ELB to prompt it to scale?  The traffic needs to be sustained for several minutes and you want to keep an eye on the DNS records while you wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We submitted a ticket to AWS. And they said their ELB is based on `requests`.

One new connection just count as one connection.

So ELB can't use for long connection server.